# Python return None when using append all in one line

Tags: python, return, append

Curious to know why using a single line for return results in None?

```
    if saveSuccess==True and msgSuccess == True:
        self.test_result.append("Saved")
        return self.test_result.append("Saved Success and Message Passed")
```

Why would the following work vs above?

```
    if saveSuccess==True and msgSuccess == True:
        self.test_result.append("Saved")
        return self.test_result
```

Comment: Because `.append()` returns None.

Answer (score 0):

`append` returns `None`, that's the reason:

```
>>> l = []
>>> print l.append('x')
None
```

We call append for its side effect of appending, not for its return value.

I needed to use print in the example above because the console doesn't show the result when it's `None`.